# Inequality with power function and binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Any suggestion on how to proceed to show:

$$\frac{2(m+1)^m -1 }{(m+1)m} - \sum_{k=0}^{m} {{m}\choose{k}} \frac{m^k}{(k+1)^2} >0 $$ where $m\geq 2$ is of course an integer.

Numerical results seem to confirm its validity.

Comment: That's an interesting problem.  Where did you encounter it?

Comment: $$
\left(\frac\partial{\partial q}q\right)^2\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk\frac{q^k}{(k+1)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mkq^k=(1+q)^m
$$

might help.

Comment: @abiessu This came up in some applied work.

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the suggestion. However, how to read $\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial q}  q \right)^2$?

Comment: As $\frac\partial{\partial q}q\frac\partial{\partial q}q$.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. I feel this is the right direction but would appreciate more light on it.